# No output in log file using Log4j and slf4j

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, log4j2

**Question** I don't get any output to the `Gamebot.log` file, but I do get it on the console and I have no idea why it doesn't output to the log. Please help.

**The code**
Log4j config file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="DEBUG" name="GameBot">
        <Appenders>
            <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
            </Console>
            <File name="MyFile" fileName="Gamebot.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
            </File>
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
            <Root level="DEBUG">
                <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" />
            </Root>
            <Root level="INFO">
                <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            </Root>

            <Logger name="wh1spr.gamebot.MessageHandler" level="Debug" additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            </Logger>


        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

The code itself

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MessageHandler {
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageHandler.class);

    ...
    @EventSubscriber
    public onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        ...
        logger.info("This should show up in both console and Gamebot.log")
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**The output**
For the file, nothing.
For the console:
Logging bot in...

```
2017-05-30 17:54:54,666 main DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/NAME/Desktop/Workspace/DiscordBot/bin/log4j2.xml]
2017-05-30 17:54:54,675 main DEBUG Installed script engines
2017-05-30 17:54:55,164 main DEBUG Oracle Nashorn Version: 1.8.0_45, Language: ECMAScript, Threading: Not Thread Safe, Compile: true, Names: {nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript}
2017-05-30 17:54:55,164 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 112 plugins
2017-05-30 17:54:55,165 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2017-05-30 17:54:55,170 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 13 plugins
2017-05-30 17:54:55,173 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2017-05-30 17:54:55,188 main DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 26 plugins
2017-05-30 17:54:55,201 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %logger{36} - %msg%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(GameBot), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2017-05-30 17:54:55,201 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 41 plugins
2017-05-30 17:54:55,202 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
2017-05-30 17:54:55,210 main DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(target="SYSTEM_OUT", follow="null", direct="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %logger{36} - %msg%n), name="Console", Configuration(GameBot), Filter=null)
2017-05-30 17:54:55,210 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
2017-05-30 17:54:55,211 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2017-05-30 17:54:55,212 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(GameBot), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2017-05-30 17:54:55,225 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender].
2017-05-30 17:54:55,230 main DEBUG FileAppender$Builder(fileName="Gamebot.log", append="false", locking="null", advertise="null", advertiseUri="null", createOnDemand="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="false", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n), name="MyFile", Configuration(GameBot), Filter=null)
2017-05-30 17:54:55,233 main DEBUG Starting FileManager Gamebot.log
2017-05-30 17:54:55,234 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
2017-05-30 17:54:55,235 main DEBUG createAppenders(={Console, MyFile})
2017-05-30 17:54:55,235 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2017-05-30 17:54:55,243 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="MyFile", level="null", Filter=null)
2017-05-30 17:54:55,244 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
2017-05-30 17:54:55,245 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="DEBUG", includeLocation="null", ={MyFile}, ={}, Configuration(GameBot), Filter=null)
2017-05-30 17:54:55,248 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2017-05-30 17:54:55,249 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="Console", level="null", Filter=null)
2017-05-30 17:54:55,249 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
2017-05-30 17:54:55,250 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="INFO", includeLocation="null", ={Console}, ={}, Configuration(GameBot), Filter=null)
2017-05-30 17:54:55,251 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2017-05-30 17:54:55,251 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="Console", level="null", Filter=null)
2017-05-30 17:54:55,252 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2017-05-30 17:54:55,256 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="false", level="DEBUG", name="wh1spr.gamebot.MessageHandler", includeLocation="null", ={Console}, ={}, Configuration(GameBot), Filter=null)
2017-05-30 17:54:55,257 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
2017-05-30 17:54:55,258 main DEBUG createLoggers(={root, root, wh1spr.gamebot.MessageHandler})
2017-05-30 17:54:55,259 main DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/NAME/Desktop/Workspace/DiscordBot/bin/log4j2.xml] initialized
2017-05-30 17:54:55,260 main DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/NAME/Desktop/Workspace/DiscordBot/bin/log4j2.xml]
2017-05-30 17:54:55,260 main DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/NAME/Desktop/Workspace/DiscordBot/bin/log4j2.xml] OK.
2017-05-30 17:54:55,263 main DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
2017-05-30 17:54:55,263 main DEBUG Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1, all resources released: true
2017-05-30 17:54:55,263 main DEBUG Appender DefaultConsole-1 stopped with status true
2017-05-30 17:54:55,264 main DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@58d25a40 OK
2017-05-30 17:54:55,325 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=73d16e93
2017-05-30 17:54:55,327 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=73d16e93,component=StatusLogger
2017-05-30 17:54:55,329 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=73d16e93,component=ContextSelector
2017-05-30 17:54:55,331 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=73d16e93,component=Loggers,name=
2017-05-30 17:54:55,332 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=73d16e93,component=Loggers,name=wh1spr.gamebot.MessageHandler
2017-05-30 17:54:55,336 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=73d16e93,component=Appenders,name=Console
2017-05-30 17:54:55,337 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=73d16e93,component=Appenders,name=MyFile
2017-05-30 17:54:55,338 main DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=73d16e93] at URI /Users/NAME/Desktop/Workspace/DiscordBot/bin/log4j2.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@2cdd0d4b) with optional ClassLoader: null
2017-05-30 17:54:55,339 main DEBUG Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
2017-05-30 17:54:55,340 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=73d16e93, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@2cdd0d4b] started OK.
17:54:55.383 [INFO ] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @1179ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
17:54:55.389 [INFO ] sx.blah.discord.Discord4J - Discord4J v2.8.1 (60523841852316689438ed3099ad7203f5bd262b-6052384) (https://github.com/austinv11/Discord4J)
17:54:55.389 [INFO ] sx.blah.discord.Discord4J - A Java binding for the official Discord API, forked from the inactive https://github.com/nerd/Discord4J. Copyright (c) 2017, Licensed under GNU LGPLv3
17:54:56.887 [INFO ] sx.blah.discord.Discord4J - Websocket Connected.
17:54:57.107 [INFO ] sx.blah.discord.Discord4J - Connected to Discord Gateway v5. Receiving 1 guilds.
GameBot is ready for action!
17:55:19.565 [DEBUG] wh1spr.gamebot.MessageHandler - Message received! Wh1spr > &&shutdown ==> This is the message that initiates shutdown (saving a few files then calling System.exit(0))
2017-05-30 17:55:19,740 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopping LoggerContext[name=73d16e93, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@2cdd0d4b]
2017-05-30 17:55:19,740 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopping LoggerContext[name=73d16e93, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@2cdd0d4b]...
2017-05-30 17:55:19,743 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Shutting down FileManager Gamebot.log
2017-05-30 17:55:19,744 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Shut down FileManager Gamebot.log, all resources released: true ==> It should've written something to the file here, yet it doesn't.
2017-05-30 17:55:19,744 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Appender MyFile stopped with status true
2017-05-30 17:55:19,744 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
2017-05-30 17:55:19,744 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false, all resources released: true
2017-05-30 17:55:19,745 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Appender Console stopped with status true
2017-05-30 17:55:19,745 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopped XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/NAME/Desktop/Workspace/DiscordBot/bin/log4j2.xml] OK
2017-05-30 17:55:19,745 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopped LoggerContext[name=73d16e93, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@2cdd0d4b] with status true
```

EDIT:
The imported libraries are

- log4j-api-2.8.2.jar
- log4j-core-2.8.2.jar
- log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar

Comment: Have you tried replacing `<File>...</File>` with `<RollingFile>...</RollingFile>` in your xml

Comment: This gives me an error "Arguments given for element RollingFile are invalid"  It is an "ConfigurationException"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ended up being longer than a comment, so I'll post it as an answer.

1. your File Appender seems to be correct.
2. It looks like you can only set the `Root level` once. So what you're actually telling log4j is something like this:

   i. "Set the root logger's level to be debug, and have it use the File appender called 'MyFile'.

   ii. But then you say, "Actually, set the root logger's level to be info, and have the appender be the Console appender called 'Console'.
3. What you were doing with the logger you defined, when you do the following:

   ```
   <Logger name="wh1spr.gamebot.MessageHandler" level="Debug" additivity="false">
           <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
   </Logger>
   ```

   tells log4j that you want to create a Logger called "wh1spr.gamebot.MessageHandler" with level set to debug, and you want it to use the Appender called `Console'. Now, since you've set the root logger's level to`INFO`, your current logger's level is Debug (which is higher precedence), so you just use the console appender.

You should be able to fix this by getting rid of the second `<Root>...</Root>`